# Where I can download latest Fedora iso?

Tags: fedora, iso

From http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/xenial/daily-live/current/ I can download the latest stable build of Ubuntu iso. Where can I find the latest build of the Fedora iso?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Fedora does have their release isos online @ https://getfedora.org/en/workstation/download/.

[For the nightly composes:](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Releases/Rawhide#Install_from_nightly_composes)

> Each day (or sometimes more than once per day) , a full 'compose' of the tree is attempted. This will usually result in the creation of all or most of the usual install, live and disk images, installer trees and so forth. The composes are synced to the `/fedora/linux/development/` directory on the mirrors, and you can find the images there.

[The rawhide repository:](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Repositories#The_rawhide_repository)

> In Rawhide - Fedora's rolling release repository, from which release are Branched before finally going stable - rawhide is the only repository. All package builds are sent there. It is represented for Yum or DNF in the fedora-rawhide.repo file in the repository path. For any system running Rawhide, it should be enabled. For any other system, it should not.
>
> The rawhide repositories for the various primary architectures can be found in the `/fedora/linux/development/rawhide` directory on the mirrors, and can also be queried from [MirrorManager](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Infrastructure/MirrorManager?rd=MirrorManager). For instance, https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/mirrorlist?repo=fedora-rawhide&arch=x86_64 will return mirrors for the x86_64 fedora repository for Rawhide.

Comment: I am looking for daily stable build. Take a look at cdimage.ubuntu link. Last updated yesterday.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing like this in Fedora. Stable versions are released and then updated using standard DNF.

There are daily builds only for the [Fedora Rawhide](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Releases/Rawhide) which is rolling release of development version of Fedora. You can download the daily ISOs directly from

https://www.happyassassin.net/nightlies.html

Answer (score 0):

I would say there: https://ftp-stud.hs-esslingen.de/pub/fedora-secondary/releases/
fedora releases are available for download there  ^^

Comment: These are 1) only secondary architectures 2) Not nightly builds and therefore it does not answer the question.

Answer (score -1):

Check this link: generated ISOs every week or so.

https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/alt/live-respins/

Comment: Related: https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Respins-SIG